# Relation between maximally mixed state and thermal state

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, entropy, density-operator, hawking-radiation

Hawking calculated the density matrix of the outgoing radiation to be a thermal state.  I have heard people say this is a maximally mixed state.  Is this because given a fixed average energy in the canonical ensemble, the maximal entropy configuration is the thermal configuration? Is maximal entropy synonymous to maximal mixing in this case?